# Generate Preview for Post to Facebook Page using the Javascript SDK or Feed Dialog

Tags: java, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

We run a java application to allow users to post to their fanpages (using graph API calls internally). We would like to generate previews of what the post would look like on facebook before posting it and found the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). However that dialog assumes the user is logged in and will post to the user wall.

Is there a way to tell that dialog to use pageID and accessToken to post to a specific page without the user being logged in?

Or: Is there any other way to generate post previews? We need this especially for link posts where facebook generates data from the target meta data and content, which is hard to emulate.

Thanks!